# Simple Neural Network (shapes images) Produces Same Outputs

Tags: python, neural-network

I work on a simple neural network for the detection of the forms, here is all the code on github: https://github.com/stodar/shapes/blob/main/saad.ipynb .

I get the same result even when I change the inputs, I redid the code several times but no result.

please do you have any idea?

````
corrects, wrongs = 0, 0

print('Target', '     Predicted', ' %')
for i in range(len(x_test)):
    input_vector = np.array(x_test[i], ndmin=2).T
    output_vector = np.dot(wh,  input_vector)
    output_vector = sigmoid(output_vector)
    output_vector = np.dot(wo, output_vector)
    res = sigmoid(output_vector)
    
    #Evaluate Model
    res_max = res.argmax()
    e = np.array(res_max)
    e = np.eye(3)[res_max]
    e.astype('int32')
    if np.array_equal(e,y_test[i]) :
        corrects += 1
    else:
        wrongs += 1
    
    print(y_test[i], ' ',e, '       ', np.max(res))
    
print("accuracy:", corrects / ( corrects + wrongs))
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The line `e.astype('int32')` doesn't change the type of e, you need to save the result

Consider changing to:

```
e = e.astype('int32')
```

or:

```
if np.array_equal(e.astype('int32'),y_test[i])
```

Another thing:
`e = np.array(res_max)` you override this line, you can just remove it.

Try run:

```
# Hidden Weight
wh = np.random.randn(no_of_hidden_nodes, no_of_in_nodes) * np.sqrt(28.0/no_of_in_nodes)
# Output Weight
wo = np.random.randn(no_of_out_nodes, no_of_hidden_nodes) * np.sqrt(28.0/no_of_hidden_nodes)

corrects, wrongs = 0, 0

print('Target', '     Predicted', ' %')
for i in range(len(x_test)):
    input_vector = np.array(x_test[i], ndmin=2).T
    output_vector = np.dot(wh,  input_vector)
    output_vector = sigmoid(output_vector)
    output_vector = np.dot(wo, output_vector)
    res = sigmoid(output_vector)
    
    #Evaluate Model
    res_max = res.argmax()
    e = np.array(res_max)
    e = np.eye(3)[res_max]
    e = e.astype('int32')
    if np.array_equal(e,y_test[i]) :
        corrects += 1
    else:
        wrongs += 1
    
    print(y_test[i], ' ',e, '       ', np.max(res))
    
print("accuracy:", corrects / ( corrects + wrongs))
```

And tell me if the result is different.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I always receive the same output, so there is an error in the code or something else.

Comment: Share an example of output and input (what is the output you always get?)

Comment: https://github.com/stodar/shapes/blob/main/saad.ipynb

Comment: what are the values of wh and wo.. you don't change them, maybe they are biased to choose always 3rd answer.
If you will random them again and re-run the code, the answer will probably change.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried but nothing new :/

Comment: # Hidden Weight
wh = np.random.randn(no_of_hidden_nodes, no_of_in_nodes) * np.sqrt(28.0/no_of_in_nodes)
# Output Weight
wo = np.random.randn(no_of_out_nodes, no_of_hidden_nodes) * np.sqrt(28.0/no_of_hidden_nodes)

Comment: The result : https://textbin.net/ytllwj7ng3